# Specific key combination not working on specific keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I don't know if this is the right community to ask in, but I've seen several "plausibly" equal questions.

I'm baffled here (after 20+ years working on IT), and don't know what to do next.

The specific key combination for the key <kbd>[</kbd> is not working on my system (Win 10 Pro x64). In my keyboard layout (es-ES), this is achieved pressing <kbd>AltGr + `</kbd>.

This is a Microsoft wired Comfort Curve 2000, with Spanish layout

At first I had assumed I could have changed my layout, however:

- That key is working fine without <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>^</kbd> (that's normal and <kbd>Shift</kbd> for that key) works fine.
- The rest of the keyboard works fine, correct layout
- Other keys requiring <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> work fine
- The layout is correct (both language and variation) in the control panel
- **It works fine using other keyboard in the same system**
- It makes no difference plugging the keyboard on other USB ports
- It worked fine till this morning (I was programming with it yesterday, I'd have noticed the lack of `[`'s)

I've tried removing the `HID` device from the Device Manager and installing it again. Also tried reverting back to the "Default" input USB device driver (instead of the specific Microsoft one).

I'm out of ideas... any hints on what to look for? Maybe hardware fault? I'm ruling out the hardware fault because other <kbd>AltGr</kbd> combinations work fine, and that specific key works fine also, it's just the specific combination of <kbd>AltGr + `</kbd> which is failing... but I might be wrong.

I'll probably go and buy another keyboard, because I need to code, but if there's any hints you might give that save me the money, I'll appreciate them.

Comment: Sounds like a key rollover problem to me. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)

Comment: @SBI could be, but it'd be the first time that has happened to me on just a single very specific combination

Comment: The "internal" handling of keys on the matrix is usually so that clashes are highly improbable, which is the reason why few people ever encounter these problems (gaming is the source of most rollover issues, which is why gaming keyboards advertise n-key-rollover). However, you might just be out of luck, and your keyboard has a clash on exactly the one combination. I've had this happen to me before as well, with different key-combinations. What's frustrating is that many keyboards have controllers with 2-key-rollover, meaning that a clash can happen with only two keys on the same matrix.

Comment: I have one more test to do. Need to try this keyboard in other computer. I don't have one handy right now, but I'll do later. If it doesn't work, I'll take it as a hardware problem and just buy a new one. That'd be too bad, I hate getting used to a different keyboard model, and this one is not available anymore :-/

Comment: @SBI definitely hardware fault, I've written an answer below. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a hardware problem. I just tested it on a different computer and it doesn't work either.

Furthermore, after plugging and unplugging the keyboard (for tests) a few times, the key stopped working alltogether (even without <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>).

Tough luck, time to shop for a new keyboard

Comment: Too bad, and good luck!